# What is the difference between a static class vs class with only static methods?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

What is the difference between a static class and class with only static methods (and for example private constructor)?

Say [we have](http://ideone.com/hpLmor):

```
using System;
 
public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                Info.SetName("nnn");
        Console.WriteLine(Info.Name);
        Info.SetName("nn2");
        Console.WriteLine(Info.Name);
        
        Info2.SetName("nnn");
        Console.WriteLine(Info2.Name);
        Info2.SetName("nn2");
        Console.WriteLine(Info2.Name);
        }
}
 
public class Info
{
    public static string Name;
    public static void SetName(string name){
        Name = name;
    }
}
 
public static class Info2
{
    public static string Name;
    public static void SetName(string name){
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

So from points of methods/properties access performance, code readabilety, code extendability?

Comment: You can create an instance of `Info` class which is useless because he has no behavior.

Answer (score 5):

A static class enforces all members to be static and prevents any instance from being created.
From MSDN:

> A class can be declared static, indicating that it contains only
>   static members. It is not possible to create instances of a static
>   class using the new keyword. Static classes are loaded automatically
>   by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program
>   or namespace containing the class is loaded.

You can read more about static classes and members here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Please attribute that quote to it's source in the MSDN documentation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker I was in the process of, got sidetracked by a colleague :P

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to come across abrasive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you declare the class as `static`, then the compiler can *enforce* for you that you didn't add any instance members and will also *ensure* that instances are *never* created (a non-`static` class with only `static` members and a `private` constructor can still have instances created inside one of the `static` methods!)

Thus, this is *legal* for a non-`static` class:

```
class Foo {
    private Foo() { }
    public static Foo Create() { return new Foo(); }
}
```

But would *not* be legal for a `static` class.

Answer (score 1):

A static class will require that all methods in that class be static, while a regular class with static methods could also have instance methods.

From a performance standpoint, static methods are slightly faster, because they do not introduce the overhead of checking for the actual instance of an object.

From a redability standpoint, static methods are generally easier to read, but may not be appropriate either, take the following for instance:

```
DAL.SavePerson();

vs.

var myRepository = new SqlRepository();
myRepository.SavePerson();
```

Answer (score 1):

Static class - Such a class cannot be instantiated. Also all the members of this class needs to be static. You will declare a class as static when you do not want a class to be instantiated again and again and want to use the object across the project. For example if you want to create a LOGGING functionality. For this you can create a static logging class and put all the (static)functionality into it for instance write method.

Non static class with static members - This class can be instantiated. Also this class can contain both static and non static members which can accessed by classname.xyz() or classname.property .You create this class when you need to create an object(class) that has some functionality(methods) that needs to be used across the application for this you might not always want to create an object of the class and access it(method). For example Redirect to home method in Navigation class.

I guess this explains most of it.

Answer (score 0):

`static class` is used when creating an instance of the class would be meaningless. For example `static class HelperMethods` vs `class HelperMethods`

```
HelperMethods.DoSomething(); // makes sense

new HelperMethods(); // absolutely no use if only contains static methods
```

Answer (score 0):

For static class you CANNOT create an instance; other case, you can always create one even if all the members and fields are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create static class instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an instance of a class which only has static methods (unless you hide the constructor).

It's not possible to create an instance of a static class, and the compiler will enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, a static class can only contain static methods. A non-static class does not have that explicit restriction and can contain both static and non-static methods.

Long answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Technically you *can create* a instance of nonstaric class with static methods only: even if the constructor is private, you can do it by means of reflection (or within static methods of the class). You can also *create a derived class* from that kind of class unless it declared as *sealed*.

Static class is always **abstract** (so you by no means can't create an isntance of it) and **sealed** (you can't create a derived class as well). So *static* class is a shortcut for *abstract sealed* class.

```
  Type tp = typeof(Info2); // <- Info2 is static class

  if (tp.IsAbstract && tp.IsSealed) { // <- And it is...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Access performance: Almost no difference.

Code readability: It's more readable to use the static modifier when the class shouldn't be instantiated, since that shows how the class is intended to be uses. Also, it adds compile-time checks to prevent using it in wrong ways by mistake.

Code extendability: No difference (regarding static members at least - of course you can extend the class with none-static members if you don't use the static modifier, but with the static modifier the class is implicitly sealed)

Additional note: Extension methods can only be declared in a static class.